# React Native - LongPress and display extra information

Tags: reactjs, react-native, setstate, touchableopacity

In React Native, I would like to achieve the following outcome (example):
[example1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BteQX.jpg) [example2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJwuN.jpg)

On Long Press of the image (or touchableOpacity), I hope to display an overlay view of some extra information (could be images or text). The information disappears when the finger leaves the screen. I was thinking if it is something related to overlay view and setState, but I could not find the function where the view only appears during long presses. Is there a way to achieve this? Or is there a module that could provide a solution?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you take a look at `react-native-image-modal` [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-modal)? Seems very close to what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the latest react native version you can use the onPressOut functionality of a pressable component: https://reactnative.dev/docs/pressable.

Trigger the show overlay with the onLongPress (or onPressIn but it's not a good UX) function and then trigger the hide overlay with onPressOut function.

For the overlay I suggest you a cool library like:
https://reactnativeelements.com/docs/tooltip/

Comment: the library is exactly what I needed! Thank you so much! :)